# check subtitles on video using protractor

Tags: typescript, webdriver, protractor

Is there a way to check visibility of subtitles on video using protractor?

I think about protractor-image-comparison.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a good idea. When you take a screenshot, you might have a different still image than the one you are expecting. Although the subtitle might not have changed, your pixels on the rest of the image might have changed. Is this a video file that you own? Can you test the subtitles independent of the web app?

Comment: it's my file. I can test subtitles only with movie.